# Список кортежей из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6, tuple

Подскажите, как можно получить результат парсинга по текстовому файлу в виде списка кортежей, то есть так:

```
[('a1b2','10','20','30'), ('g5j9','40','15','5'), ('k5j8','20','24','38'), ...]
```

Пример текста:

```
Code a1b2
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 10
Angle_b 20
Angle_c 30
<много ненужного текста>
Code g5j9
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 40
Angle_b 15
Angle_c 5
<много ненужного текста>
Code k5j8
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 20
Angle_b 24
Angle_c 38
И так далее...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = """\
Code a1b2
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 10
Angle_b 20
Angle_c 30
<много ненужного текста>
Code g5j9
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 40
Angle_b 15
Angle_c 5
<много ненужного текста>
Code k5j8
<много ненужного текста>
Angle_a 20
Angle_b 24
Angle_c 38
И так далее...
"""


def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i: i + n]


import re
items = re.findall(r'Code (\w\d\w\d)|Angle_\w (\d+)', text)

result = []

for row in chunks(items, n=4):
    # Пример данных в row: [('a1b2', ''), ('', '10'), ('', '20'), ('', '30')]

    code, angle_a, angle_b, angle_c = row
    result.append((code[0], angle_a[1], angle_b[1], angle_c[1]))

print(result)
```

Консоль:

```
[('a1b2', '10', '20', '30'), ('g5j9', '40', '15', '5'), ('k5j8', '20', '24', '38')]
```